# Field is not writeble (User)

Tags: apex

I have a class to create an User but I'm getting these errors trying to deploy:

> === Deploy Errors
> PROJECT PATH                                                        ERRORS
> ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────  ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────
> force-app\main\default\classes\OneSFA_SalesStructureHandler_ws.cls  Field is not writeable: User.AccountId (446:49)
> force-app\main\default\classes\OneSFA_SalesStructureHandler_ws.cls  Field is not writeable: User.IsPortalEnabled (446:49)
>
> 10:57:47.675 ended SFDX: Deploy Source to Org

This is the code:

```
private without sharing class AsyncCreateUser implements Queueable {
        
        private String accId;
        private String usrRep;
        private List<Contact> lstContact;
        private List<Sales_Structure__c> lstSSUp;
        
        private asyncCreateUser(String accId, String usrRep, List<Contact> lstContact, List<Sales_Structure__c> lstSSUp){
            this.accId      = accId;
            this.usrRep     = usrRep;
            this.lstContact = lstContact;
            this.lstSSUp    = lstSSUp;
            
            System.debug('Create Contact - accId ' + this.accId);
            System.debug('Create Contact - usrRep ' + this.usrRep);
            System.debug('Create Contact - lstSSUp ' + this.lstSSUp);
        }
        
        public void execute(QueueableContext context){
            if (!Schema.sObjectType.Contact.isUpdateable()) {
                return;
            }
            
           //List<Contact> lstContact = new List<Contact>();
            List<User> lstUser       = new List<User>();
            
            Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Customer Community Plus Login User'];
            
            for(Sales_Structure__c ss : lstSSUp){    
                for(Contact cct : lstContact){
                    User userXP               = new User(
                    AccountId                 = accId,
                    ContactId                 = cct.Id,
                    IsPortalEnabled           = true,
                    FirstName                 = cct.FirstName,
                    LastName                  = cct.LastName,
                    Alias                     = cct.LastName+ss.SalesRep__c,
                    SAP_Number_of_SalesRep__c = ss.SalesRep__c,
                    Division_Allocation__c    = cct.Department__c,
                    Email                     = cct.Email,
                    UserName                  = cct.Email+ss.SalesRep__c+'.store', 
                    ProfileId                 = p.Id, 
                    EmailEncodingKey          = 'UTF-8',
                    LanguageLocaleKey         = 'en_US',
                    LocalesIdKey              = 'en_US',
                    TimezonesIdKey            = 'America/Los_Angeles'
                    );
                    insert userXP;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I handle this error?

Comment: You can not attempt to write to those fields. *Sorry - couldn't resist.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This field is read only. You can see the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_user.htm).
You can fill this field indirectly by populating `ContactId` field with a valid contact record Id. Also, please make sure that that the contact have an associated account. From the developer docs about `ContactId` on `User` Sobject, the description states

> ID of the Contact associated with this account. The contact must have a value in the AccountId field or an error occurs.
> This is a relationship field.